# ArrayList empty while accessing it in another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

1. Prepared a toy class.

   ```
   public class toy {

     public String name;
     public int id;
     public int price;

     public toy(String name, int id, int price) {
         this.name = name;
         this.id = id;
         this.price = price;
     }
     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
     public int getId() {
         return id;
     }
     public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
     public int getPrice() {
         return price;
     }
     public void setPrice(int price) {
         this.price = price;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Prepared another class to hold as list of toys. Same class provides getter and setter methods for the list of toys.

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   public class accMeth {

       public static ArrayList<toy> toylist=new ArrayList<toy>();

       public ArrayList<toy> getToylist() {
           return toylist;
       }

       public void setToylist(ArrayList<toy> toylist) {
          this.toylist = toylist;
       }

   }
   ```
3. This class below creates and adds toys in toyList. Then setting the toyList using setter.

   ```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class adding extends accMeth {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            toy t1= new toy("gg",1,20);
            toy t2 = new toy("gg",2,23);

            accMeth meth=new accMeth();

            toylist.add(t1);
            toylist.add(t2);
            meth.setToylist(toylist);
            System.out.println(meth.getToylist().get(1).getPrice());
        }
    }
   ```
4. Now if I want to access list, here it appears to be empty.

   ```
    public class getting{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            adding ad= new adding();
            System.out.println(ad.getToylist().isEmpty());
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Why should it not be empty at that point ?

Comment: I think because I added it in 3 and now accessing it making a new instance in 4. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You constructed a new adding() but that would not trigger the `main` method inside it

Comment: There are so many Java syntax violations here I dont know where to start but it looks like you need to add your logic for the accMeth class into the constructor and not into static void main! Get a copy of Oreilly Head First Java and digest!

Comment: what should i do for that?

Comment: I'm seeing 2 psvm, don't know where to check first. Please edit your question and improve formatting.

Comment: @AnamayPandey It seems to me you are a beginner to programming. Because there are huge number of wrong naming conventions in your code.So please first go through a proper tutorial to learn how to name classes and variable especially.Since you are a beginner to stack overflow first go through this link about how to ask a good question  in stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

it's empty because you fill it in an instance  in 3 and printing from a new instance in 4

the main point is that `public void setToylist(ArrayList<toy> toylist) { this.toylist = toylist; }`  you used `this` and it will add the value to this instant

if you want to use the static  defend in 2  delete the `this` from the set method and access it as Static

```
public static void setToylist(ArrayList<toy> toylistar) {
toylist = toylistar;
}
```

now you marked the method as static and now you have to use it statickly

```
toy t1= new toy("gg",1,20);
toy t2 = new toy("gg",2,23);



 toylist.add(t1);
 toylist.add(t2);
accMeth .setToylist(toylist);

System.out.println(accMeth.getToylist().get(1).getPrice());


}
```

now you can find the change in the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

adding ad= new adding();
System.out.println(accMeth.getToylist().isEmpty());


}
```

but don't forget to put the add to contracter in number 3

```
import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class adding extends accMeth { public  adding () {

toy t1= new toy("gg",1,20);
toy t2 = new toy("gg",2,23);


 toylist.add(t1);
 toylist.add(t2);
accMeth.setToylist(toylist);

System.out.println(accMeth.getToylist().get(1).getPrice());


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Class Toy.java:

> name, id and price variables should be private. Constructor should be
> Toy instead of toy

```
public class Toy {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int price;

    public Toy (String name, int id, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

2. Class accMeth:

> Should be AccMeth. 'toylist' should not be public and static since,
> you have employed getter and setters. Plus, you will be modifying it. Check [java Aceess Modifiers](https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers)

```
public class AccMeth {

    private ArrayList toylist = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList<Toy> getToylist() {
        return toylist;
    }

    public void setToylist(ArrayList<Toy> toylist) {
        this.toylist = toylist;
    }
}
```

3. class adding

> No need to extend the other class as it is in your code. I mean, you
> could directly access the ArrayList from the class that is the
> execution point. i.e. holds the main method.

```
public class Adding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Toy t1 = new Toy("gg", 1, 20);
        Toy t2 = new Toy("gg", 2, 23);

        AccMeth meth = new AccMeth();
        ArrayList<Toy> toylist = meth.getToylist();
        toylist.add(t1);
        toylist.add(t2);
        meth.setToylist(toylist);

        System.out.println(meth.getToylist().get(1).getPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of good explanations. But you should probably start with explaining that the main() method in the third snippet ... doesnt get called, and thus that the assumption "that main() method created some objects" is simply plain wrong.

Answer (score -1):

you should move block code: "adding toy to list" to adding constructor